# How can I debug a non-working wire:click element in Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to get to grips with Livewire. I have the [Quickstart demo](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart) working. That is an up/down counter that looks like this.

### Working demo code

routes/web.php:

```
use App\Livewire\Counter;

...

Route::get('/counter', Counter::class);
```

app/livewire/counter.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 1;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function decrement()
    {
        $this->count--;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

resources/views/livewire/counter.blade.php:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>

    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>

    <button wire:click="decrement">-</button>
</div>
```

OK, so this works. The component is rendered inside the layout, and the plus and minus buttons send AJAX operations to the server.

### My use case

I want to inject a component at a predefined point, and I want to do it on click, not on initial page render.

I have this code in a standard Laravel template:

```
<button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-md"
        wire:click="generate-titles">
    Generate titles
</button>
```

At the top of the template, I have this anonymous class:

```
<?php

use Livewire\Volt\Component;

new class extends Component
{
    /**
     * Log the current user out of the application.
     */
    public function generateTitles()
    {
        return view('wire.generate-titles');
    }
}; ?>
```

This is similar to a "logout" feature created by Laravel Breeze.

However clicking my button does not do anything, including not sending any AJAX request, or
appending something to the error log. I am aware that I have not given Livewire an indication of where to render the component, and that's because I don't want to render on page load.

Now I did try rendering the component on page load anyway, by putting this in the template:

```
<livewire:generate-titles :result="">
```

I also created a class-based component at app/livewire/GenerateTitles.php, thus:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class GenerateTitles extends Component
{
    public string $result;

    // Put mount() here?

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.generate-titles');
    }
}
```

However that results in an initial page crash with this fatal Laravel error:

> local.ERROR: Latest compiled component path not found

I expect the answer is somewhere in the comprehensive docs, but I fear I have reading blindness. What can I try next?

### Update

I have a partial success, in the rendering of a component on page load. Instead of a `<livewire:>` tag, I use this in the Blade view:

```
use App\Livewire\GenerateTitles;

...

@livewire(GenerateTitles::class)
```

I wonder if the `<livewire:>` does not accurately specify the namespace of the component that I want.

However, this is not:

- rendered via injected AJAX operation
- loaded on a click event

Comment: One thing I could try is to put the button with the `wire:click` device inside the component. Maybe that would link it with the component I would want to refresh on click? I don't want to keep doing shots in the dark though.

Comment: ^ OK, putting the event triggering item in a component view does wire it up correctly. Perhaps this loads the JavaScript that attaches the click event to the DOM. Now my component won't have a result on page load, so I don't want it to render until the click is received. I thus still need to discover an answer on that.

Comment: Ah, I have found an approach that doesn't feel too hacky. The component does still render at page load, but the public property containing the actual content to render can be empty, and thus the initial load is essentially a null rendering. When the click happens, it will call an API, get real content, and upload the component to show the update.